# How to make a simple dialog system with yes/no options and pages?

Tags: unity

I recently made dialogues. Now I want to add the option to choose yes/no when the dialogue is finished (if it has a choice).

Adding buttons to the dialogue is no problem, the problem I'm having is that I want a "generic" dialogue system. By that I mean, I might have 200 NPCs, and depending on which NPC I am talking to, the yes/no buttons will react differently. This is where I'm stuck. How will the buttons know which methods to call?

Say I have one NPC that offers to sell me an item for 100 gold, and another NPC that offers to show me around the village. How will my system know which functions to call when I press "Yes"?

All I can find on this subject is really complicated using trees and things I don't fully understand yet, and don't really need, since my system is very simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you go:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using DG.Tweening;
using UnityEngine.Events;

[RequireComponent (typeof(CanvasGroup))]
public class GenericDialog : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text title;
    public Text message;
    public Text accept, decline;
    public Button acceptButton, declineButton;

    private CanvasGroup cg;

    void Awake(){
        cg = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }

    public GenericDialog OnAccept(string text, UnityAction action){
        accept.text = text;
        acceptButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        acceptButton.onClick.AddListener(action);
        return this;
    }



    public GenericDialog OnDecline(string text, UnityAction action){
        decline.text = text;
        declineButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        declineButton.onClick.AddListener(action);
        return this;
    }

    public GenericDialog Title(string title){
        this.title.text = title;
        return this;
    }

    public GenericDialog Message(string message){
        this.message.text = message;
        return this;
    }

    // show the dialog, set it's canvasGroup.alpha to 1f or tween like here
    public void Show(){
        this.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        cg.DOKill();
        cg.blocksRaycasts = true;
        cg.interactable = true;
        cg.DOFade(1f, 0.3f);
    }

    public void Hide(){
        cg.DOKill();
        cg.interactable = false;
        cg.DOFade(0f, 0.3f).OnComplete(() => cg.blocksRaycasts = false);
    }

    private static GenericDialog instance;
    public static GenericDialog Instance() {
        if(!instance){
            instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof (GenericDialog)) as GenericDialog;
            if(!instance)
                Debug.Log("There need to be at least one active GenericDialog on the scene");
        }

        return instance;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
GenericDialog dialog = GenericDialog.Instance();
dialog.SetTitle("Hello player!");
dialog.SetMessage("Do you want to exchange some gems for 100 gold?");
dialog.SetOnAccept("Yes", () => { // define what happens when user clicks Yes:
    if(player.HasGems(10)){
        player.RemoveGems(10);
        player.AddGold(100);
    }
    dialog.Hide();
});

dialog.SetOnDecline("No thanks", () => dialog.Hide());
dialog.Show();
```

You can chain these like:

```
dialog.SetTitle("ABC").SetMessage("DEF").Show(); // cause of a builder pattern
```

Now, create your beautiful dialog on the scene, add `Text` components, `Buttons` and more. Also, add a `CanvasGroup` to fade the dialog in and out.

Add this `GenericDialog` script to the `dialog's gameobject` on the `scene` and drag and drop your components on that script's fields.

You can access the above code from anywhere cause of a singleton pattern.

Feel free to ask any questions!

If you don't use any `Tweening` library like `DOTween`, just change `Show()` method contents to:

```
public void Show(){
    this.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
    cg.interactable = true;
    cg.alpha = 1f;
    cg.blockRaycasts = true;
}
```

and `Hide()` method too.

## Dialog with pages

Ok so, first of all, we create a `Page` script and add this code to it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
[RequireComponent (typeof(CanvasGroup))]
public class Page : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text pageText;
    private CanvasGroup cg;

    void Awake(){
        cg = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }

    public void Show(){
        this.cg.alpha = 1f;
        this.cg.interactable = true; // in case it's a scrollview or something and you want to scroll - it has to be interactable to allow clicks
        this.cg.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    public void Hide(){
        this.cg.alpha = 0f;
        this.cg.interactable = false;
        this.cg.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
}
```

Then, we create an object like here, add a `Page` component to it and attach the one object - `Text` to the script.

[image]

Then, you need to make the page a `PREFAB` - so just move the page object to the `Assets window` from the scene. When it becomes blue, we're done. You can remove the object from the scene. We'll use the prefab later.

Now we create the PageableDialog class. I've explained how it works inside.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System;

[RequireComponent (typeof(CanvasGroup))]
public class PageableDialog : MonoBehaviour {

    // title and subtitle for the entire dialog, like NPC name and quest name or something
    public Text title, subtitle;

    // buttons and their text components (Prev/Next and on the last page - Accept)
    public Text nextText, prevText;
    public Button prevButton, nextButton;

    // accept text when we're on the last page of the dialog
    private string acceptText = "Accept Quest"; 

    // what happens when user clicks Accept
    private UnityAction onAcceptAction;

    // canvas group for the entire dialog
    private CanvasGroup cg;

    // prefab for the page object (it has just a text component)
    public Page pagePrefab;

    // list of pages (added through AddPage())
    public List<Page> pages = new List<Page>();

    // current page index 
    private int _currentPage;


    void Awake(){
        cg = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();

        _currentPage = 0;

        // prevbutton always shows the previous page so (currentPage - 1)
        prevButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
            if(_currentPage > 0){ // so we don't exceed the pages list
                ShowPage(_currentPage - 1);
            }
        });

        // nextButton always shows the next page (current + 1)
        nextButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
            if(_currentPage < pages.Count - 1){ // so we don't exceed the pages list
                ShowPage(_currentPage + 1);
            }
        });
    }

    // you can customize this method and the Page class so it has some scrolls, buttons etc.
    // you can add different AddPage methods simultanously, one which adds a scrollview, one adds a text etc. 
    // then, customize the Page class
    public void AddPage(string pageText){
        Page page = Instantiate(pagePrefab, this.transform);
        page.pageText.text = pageText;
        pages.Add(page);

    }

    // what happens on the last page, when user clicks Accept
    public PageableDialog OnAccept(string text, UnityAction action){
        acceptText = text;
        onAcceptAction = action;
        return this;
    }

    public PageableDialog SetTitle(string title){
        this.title.text = title;
        return this;
    }

    public PageableDialog SetSubtitle(string subtitle){
        this.subtitle.text = subtitle;
        return this;
    }

    public void Hide(){
        cg.alpha = 0f;
        cg.interactable = false;
        cg.blocksRaycasts = false;

        // destroy or reset, better destroy cause we create dialogs in DialogManager
        // when we're finished, we destroy the dialog object. reset is not needed, you can remove it.
        Reset();
        Destroy(this.gameObject); 
    }

    // we show the entire dialog and then, show the first page instantly.
    // we also setasLastSibling to make the dialog on top of other things on canvas.
    public void Show(){
        this.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
        cg.alpha = 1f;
        cg.interactable = true;
        cg.blocksRaycasts = true;

        // show the 1st page

        if(pages.Count > 0){
            ShowPage(0);
        } else throw new Exception ("We have an error, m4te! Wrong implementation. You have to add pages to the dialog before showing it.");
    }

    public void ShowPage(int pageNum){

        // safety check
        if(pageNum < 0 || pageNum >= pages.Count)
            pageNum = 0;

        // we set the currentpage
        _currentPage = pageNum;

        // if we show page 0, we disable the "Prev" button
        if(_currentPage == 0) prevButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        else prevButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        // if we're showing the last page, we change the button's text to our accept text, like "Accept Quest" and add the OnAcceptAction to be performed when clicked.
        if(_currentPage == (pages.Count - 1)){
            nextText.text = acceptText;
            nextButton.onClick.AddListener(onAcceptAction);
        } 
        else // otherwise, we remove this listener or it would accept the quest on each page :D
        {
            nextText.text = "Next Page";
            nextButton.onClick.RemoveListener(onAcceptAction);
        }

        // finally, we iterate through pages, show the one we picked and hide the rest.
        for(int i=0;i<pages.Count;i++){
            if(i == pageNum){
                pages[i].Show();
            } else pages[i].Hide();
        }


    }

    // if you want to reuse dialogs, use this method to reset them, but don't reuse. 
    private void Reset(){
        foreach(Page p in pages){
            p.Hide();
        }

        _currentPage = 0;
    }

}
```

Then, we create a dialog on the scene so it looks similar to this:

[image]

Then, add a `PageableDialog` component to your new dialog. Remember to add a `CanvasGroup` to the main object. Then, two things.

Drop the `Page prefab` (this one made before) onto the `PageableDialog` object on the scene and set it's width/height so it looks like you want on the dialog. Then, drop the Page back onto the prefab to save changes and REMOVE Page object from the `PageableDialog` so it looks exactly like on the image above.

Then, set the `CanvasGroup` alpha back to 0 so it's invisible during start and save `PageableDialog` as a prefab too so you have two prefabs now.

Here's how it should look like:

[image]

Finally, create a 3rd class, `DialogsManager`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DialogsManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public PageableDialog pdPrefab;
    public Canvas canvas; // dialogs must be on some canvas

    public PageableDialog CreatePageableDialog(){
        return Instantiate(pdPrefab, canvas.transform);
    }

    private static DialogsManager instance;
    public static DialogsManager Instance() {
        if(!instance){
            instance = FindObjectOfType(typeof (DialogsManager)) as DialogsManager;
            if(!instance)
                Debug.Log("There need to be at least one active DialogsManager on the scene");
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

A singleton pattern creates a new dialog for us. We can customize it and show, wherever we want.

To use a dialog, make some button on your scene and make it run this code:

```
PageableDialog dialog = DialogsManager.Instance().CreatePageableDialog();
dialog.AddPage("Hello there 1");
dialog.AddPage("Hello there 2");
dialog.AddPage("Hello there 3");
dialog.OnAccept("Accept!", () => { 
    Debug.Log("FINISHED");
    dialog.Hide();
});
dialog.SetTitle("Some NPC");
dialog.SetSubtitle("Some quest");
dialog.Show();
```

Also, create a `Close Button` in the `PageableDialog` prefab. Make it run method `PageableDialog.Hide()` like there:

[image]

so it closes and destroys the dialog.

If you're lazy, here's a complete package I've just shown above:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lirllhhx3afaag0/DialogsScene.unitypackage?dl=0

Create a new project, click `Assets -> Import -> Custom Package`. 
Open the `TestScene` and click the button in the game.

Have fun! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like exactly what I need with a few modifications :)
Without having tested it the only question I have is it possible to create, for example, 4 "pages" (i.e click to get more text), and then display a page with options?

Comment: You could make another class, for example `PageableDialog` and modify it so it has a list of `PageDialogs` (single dialogs, but not singletons!!!). Then, in the `PageableDialog` we'd need to create a method `AddPage(string message)` which would add a new page, modify the `Show()` method to show only the first page and mess with listeners, so they swap pages until the last page. 

I'll write it when I come back home in couple hours ;)

Comment: Love you get back safely

Comment: This is a brilliant idea. Good job.

Comment: Here you go guys, I've added pageable dialogs. Love you

Comment: @Spectre Stay awsome!

Comment: Works like a charm. Btw, Exception: `We have an error, m4te! Wrong implementation. You have to add pages to the dialog before showing it` Is thrown even if you create pages before calling show() :) Even in your own example of how to call it, that happens. At least for me.Still works tho. Think you might have forgotten an else-statement?

Comment: Also, any special reason we are setting alpha to 0 instead of turning active on/off?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I didn't add the else statement before: `throw new Exception ("We have an error..."` It was end of the function so it worked. This exception is there only to inform you that you forgot to add pages somewhere. There are two reasons of setting alpha instead of active on/off. First - it gives you the ability to [tween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/) values if you want to make the transition smooth so it looks more realistic and friendly. Second - it's faster than `SetActive()` if you have many objects on the scene because `SA()` needs to iterate through the objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response, I created something a little less object oriented to manage the dialog.  Also, I couldn't get the CanvasGroup working, so I went with a panel.  But it does require use of some magic strings.

Create a Panel that contains two Text and two Button named: title, message, button1, button2

(you can tweak the code and visual to suit your needs)

Also, if you want the popup to appear to be modal, create two panels.  The outer one will anchor center with zero margins and have a dark semitransparent image.  Then the child panel will be this dialog

[image: dialog prefab example]

I stored the panel as a prefab, but not sure if that's really necessary.
Be sure to set the panel to inactive at design time

This technique could also be expanded to ask the user for input.  Add an InputField, and change the Actions into

```
Action<string>
```

Calling code:

```
public class ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button Button;
    public GameObject Dialog;  //this is the panel
    //public GameObject Dialog_Another;

    void Start()
    {
        Button.onClick.AddListener(Button_Clicked);
    }

    private void Button_Clicked()
    {
        YesNoDialog.ShowDialog
        (
            Dialog,
            "Sanity Check",
            "Are you sure?",

            "No",
            null,

            "Yes",
            () => Button.image.color = UnityEngine.Random.ColorHSV(0, 1)
        );
    }
}
```

Wrapper that sets up and shows/hides the panel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public static class YesNoDialog
{
    //NOTE: If the panel you're using doesn't have title or message, the value passed in will be ignored
    public static void ShowDialog(GameObject panel, string title, string message, string button1Text, Action clicked1, string button2Text, Action clicked2)
    {
        Text[] labels = panel.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

        Text lblTitle = labels.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "title");
        if (lblTitle != null)
            lblTitle.text = title ?? "";

        Text lblMsg = labels.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "message");
        if (lblMsg != null)
            lblMsg.text = message ?? "";

        Button[] buttons = panel.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();

        var btn1 = buttons.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "button1");
        if (btn1 != null)
            SetupButton(panel, btn1, button1Text, clicked1);

        var btn2 = buttons.FirstOrDefault(o => o.name == "button2");
        if (btn2 != null)
            SetupButton(panel, btn2, button2Text, clicked2);

        panel.SetActive(true);
    }

    private static void SetupButton(GameObject panel, Button button, string text, Action clicked)
    {
        Text label = button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
        if (label != null)
            label.text = text;

        button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            clicked?.Invoke();
            panel.SetActive(false);
        });
    }
}
```